# What happens with eclipse when I close and reopen a project?

Tags: spring, eclipse

I am quite new in Spring tools Suite.Recently, I have downloaded it from `spring.io(spring-tool-suite-3.9.3.RELEASE-e4.7.3-win32-x86_64)`.I have created sample Maven project and when I run it. It showed me following error message:

Console error logs:

```
Mar 28, 2018 8:47:32 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1f17ae12: startup date [Wed Mar 28 20:47:32 BDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 28, 2018 8:47:33 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/springpractice/first/test/beans/beans.xml]
Mar 28, 2018 8:47:33 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4cdbe50f: defining beans [patient,address]; root of factory hierarchy
Mar 28, 2018 8:47:33 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4cdbe50f: defining beans [patient,address]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'patient' defined in class path resource [com/springpractice/first/test/beans/beans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValidationException: Couldn't find an init method named 'beaninit' on bean with name 'patient'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.springpractice.first.test.App.main(App.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValidationException: Couldn't find an init method named 'beaninit' on bean with name 'patient'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 12 more
```

I created a bean.xml configuration file which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="patient" class="com.springpractice.first.test.Patient"
        scope="singleton" init-method="beaninit">
        <constructor-arg value="16" name="id"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg value="Jerry" name="name"></constructor-arg>
        <property name="nid" value="123456"></property>
        <property name="address" ref="address"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="address" class="com.springpractice.first.test.Address">
        <constructor-arg name="street" value="Dhormotola"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg name="postcode" value="7400"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My  `patient.java` looks like:

```
package com.springpractice.first.test;

    public class Patient {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int nid;
    private Address address;

    public Patient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void beaninit() {
        System.out.println("Patient created : " + this);
    }

    public void beandestroy() {
        System.out.println("Patient is destroyed");
    }

    public Patient(int id, String name) {
        // super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }



    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getNid() {
        return nid;
    }

    public void setNid(int nid) {
        this.nid = nid;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Patient [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", nid=" + nid + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }

    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("want to be played");
    }

}
```

In many times, I have seen that when I create a new project and run it the first time it show me some error.But when I close that project `( project -> close)` and reopen it `( project -> open)`, three is no error exist.The project compiles and runs fine.In this case, that was happening.

**So, I want to know that what happens with eclipse when I close and open a project and why errors removed.**

Comment: Stacktrace clearly states that your class `Patient` is missing `beaninit` method. Maybe it is a generated class and Eclipse generates it after some of your actions? What is inside the class?

Comment: There is no error in my code.when I close and reopen this project,it worked fine.

Comment: Basically, I want to know that when I close and reopen some projects, all errors be removed .why?

Comment: When you create a new project, how do you compile it initially? Might be you Eclipse has not configured to autocompile?

Comment: yes.I got it.There was a petty mistake.